# How can I remove specify string words with php

Tags: php

How can I remove string . I want to find string that've 2018 then I want to delete string until ,

```
{"2018-1-8":0,"2018-1-9":0,"2018-1-10":0,"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}
```

How can I display like this

```
 {"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}
```

**Note** I want to remove `"2018-1-8":0,"2018-1-9":0,"2018-1-10":0,`

Comment: Is it json string or php array?

Comment: I store it as string @splash58

Comment: Can you transform it as array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is valid **JSON** which you can parse using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You can then modify the data as you want:

```
// Your string
$json = '{"2018-1-8":0,"2018-1-9":0,"2018-1-10":0,"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}';

// Get it as an array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Pass by reference
foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {

    // Remove if key contains '2018'
    if (strpos($key, '2018') !== false) {
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}

// Return the updated JSON
echo json_encode($data);

// Output: {"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}
```

Another solution using [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

array_walk($data, function ($v, $k) use (&$data) {
    if (strpos($k, '2018') !== false) { unset($data[$k]); }
});

echo json_encode($data);
// Output: {"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}
```

---

See also:

- [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)
- [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
- [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @TryHardz I added another solution, much shorter, if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe :

```
// Your string
$string = "{\"2018-1-8\":0,\"2018-1-9\":0,\"2018-1-10\":0,\"2019-1-1\":0,\"2019-1-15\":0}";
// Transform it as array
$array = json_decode($string);
// Create a new array
$new_array = array();

// Now loop through your array
foreach ($array as $date => $value) {
    // If the first 4 char of your $date is not 2018, then add it in new array
    if (substr($date, 0, 4) !== "2018")
        $new_array[$date] = $value;
}
// Now transform your new array in your desired output
$new_string = json_encode($new_array);
```

Output of `var_dump($new_string);` is `{"2019-1-1":0,"2019-1-15":0}`